# Scrollbar always shows over dropdown

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro, design, google-chrome

***Is this bug?***

[image]g?

Link to question:

[AddTarget does not work on UITextField rightView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711401/addtarget-does-not-work-on-uitextfield-rightview)

*I am not able to move this cursor and cursor always come above the Achievements box.*

*Chrome is most updated for MAC*

[image]

This is about my MAC

[image]

Comment: No repro on latest Chrome/Opera on Windows 8.1

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Chrome 48.0.2564.97 (64-bit) on OS X 10.11.3.

Comment: @Mat: the scrollbar is a default Chrome scrollbar on Mac. Mine look just the same. They just don't overlap like that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : I have added my mac config screenshot too... may be it will help you mods...

Comment: We cannot reproduce this - disable all add-ons/plugins/extensions, reboot and see if this is still happening.

Comment: @FahimParkar: it's helpful in that it shows that you are using an older OS X release; if this is a bug, it is one in Chrome on Yosemite, not with the Stack Overflow site design.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : I understand... I am not saying its SO site design issue... I found this so I thought to inform you mods... if its chrome issue, its okay... I can handle screen using mac mouse which is fine with me...  that's why I asked "Is this bug?"...

Comment: Did you set your scroll bars to show always (in your OS preferences)?

Comment: @FahimParkar thank you for posting, always post if unsure! I can't help much here because we don't control the bug...but the Chrome team can. I think you'll want to weigh in on an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=571256&q=scrollbars%20layer&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: No repro ie 6 on xp

Answer (score 0):

I can't repro this on 10.11.3 (same Chrome) here: [image]

It's either Yosemite specific, or something else local on your end would be my guess - either way: a Chrome bug?

Comment: You seem to have the scrollbar always visible. In this case I cannot reproduce it either. But when I have scollbar only turning visible while scrolling, I see the reported behavior. [Tweak accordingly to reproduce in System Preferences => General => Show scollbars]